# Uploading a video to S3 AWS from Android app results in a 0Kb file

Tags: android, video, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Android app can upload photos to S3 AWS taken by the camera directly or chosen from the galery. Now I want the app to upload videos from the gallery as well. But the uploaded file size is always 0Kb.

This is the code for the video picking process:

```
Intent videoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
videoPickerIntent.setType("video/*");
getActivity().startActivityForResult(videoPickerIntent, SELECT_VIDEO);
```

Then, I get the video path (I've tested the path I get playing the video inside a VideoView in the same app). (example: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140903_163147.mp4")

And, finally, I use a PutObjectRequest in an AsyncTask, similarly to the way I upload photos.

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, nameInAwsWithPath, videoPath);
por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
s3Client.putObject(por);
```

And then, in S3 I can see a file, named as expected, but empty. 0 Kb size.

What's going wrong?

Comment: If you have logcat open when you run this code, are there any exceptions or error messages? It's possible that an exception is being thrown on a separate thread making it not obvious that it's happening.

Comment: There are no errors or warnings at all in logcat. The putobject is inside a try/catch and everything seems to go well... but I get the empty file on AWS.

Comment: now I've declared the: 
PutObjectRequest por;
at the begining of the doInBackground method and instantiated it at the end:
por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, nameInAwsWithPath, videoPath);
por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
s3Client.putObject(por);

and it works

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: could you post the whole code? i am having the same trouble/cant figure out how to upload my video my my S3 from Android :(

Comment: I'm not working with that app anymore. At that time, the latest version of S3 library was v3. I know that v4 was released and v3 was deprecated and stopped working, so I don't know if it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the code:

```
private class S3PutVideoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.uploadingvideo));
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            boolean result = true;
            // Put the video data into S3.
            try {

                PutObjectRequest por;

                String filename = "img_" + xxxxx[pos].id + "_"
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".avi";

                File fileToUpload = new File(mCurrentAbsoluteVideoPath);

                SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GlobalPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String bucket = prefs.getString("bucket", PICTURE_BUCKET);

                por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, filename, fileToUpload);

                por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                s3Client.putObject(por);

            } catch (Exception exception) {

                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            if (!result) {
                //show error
            } else {
                fileUploaded = true;
                dismissUpload();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the code that @user6042879 has requested (an answer that shows how I corrected the issue back then)

Comment: So you probably should accept it to make it clear that the issue was solved.

Comment: Thank you! You also haven't checked if this code worked? this must be pretty old code now lol :D

Comment: One year and a half already! The button just disappeared from the app :D